# Discrepancy in Entry Page URL in Adobe Analytics API with Python with Omniture

Tags: python-3.x, api, adobe-analytics

Entry Page URLs are different while calling Adobe Analytics API using Python when compared same with Data Virtuality Studio. For some orders, it's matching perfectly but for a few, it does not match. I am lost why it happens to a few orders to give a brief idea I had attached the screenshot [Difference In Entry Page URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPRyK.png).
Thanks!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO! I'm not familiar with the tools you're using but looking at this question I wonder if those who are will be able to reproduce the issue you have. Please add a bit more detail to make your inconsistency reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks! Michael. Initially, I was pulling the data for Adobe Analytics using the Data virtuality tool which has its own connector for getting the data from the API. Now as we are transitioning we had developed the python script to pull the data from the API all the other data is matching but for the EntryPage URL we are facing a discrepancy in the URL which I had attached an example for. Data discrepancy is around 2-3 % overall but still why the EntryPage URL is matching for some orders while it doesn't match for other ones.Let me know if I am missing some details on

Comment: I think what's missing is code and/or examples so someone can reproduce and troubleshoot this behavior.

Comment: There are many possible reasons for this, ranging from dates (including timezone) you vs. web interface are using, report suite used, segments, filters, user permissions, etc. The easiest way to trouble-shoot your issue is to look at the API endpoint payload the interface uses and compare it to yours. In Workspace, you can enable debugging to look at the API endpoint payload(s) it is using. This guide is a bit dated but the principles are the same. e.g. in Workspace in the Help menu dropdown there is option to enable debugging (and a bug icon top right of a report section), vs. js console

Comment: doc link: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics-learn/tutorials/apis/using-analysis-workspace-to-build-api-2-requests.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks! Michael and Crayon for helping me in this surely I will take a look at the docs.Thanks again